# setInterval() not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Hi i'm quite new to java script and for some reason `setInterval` does not seem to work when i run this code on `firefox`. Ive tried running it on `Microsoft` edge but it still does not work. It just prints out the date once but does not continue from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    <!--Intervals with Date/time-->
    function printTime(){
        var now = new Date();
        var hours = now.getHours();
        var mins = now.getMinutes();
        var seconds = now.getSeconds();
        document.write(hours+":"+mins+":"+seconds+"<br \>");
    }

    setInterval("printTime()", 1000);//in ms

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write(` is 1990's code - don't use it at all ... also `setInterval("printTime()", 1000)` in code less than 30 years old is written `setInterval(printTime, 1000)`

```js
   function printTime(){
        var now = new Date();
        var hours = now.getHours();
        var mins = now.getMinutes();
        var seconds = now.getSeconds();
        document.body.innerHTML += (hours+":"+mins+":"+seconds+"<br \>");
    }

    setInterval(printTime, 1000);//in ms
```

The reason document.write fails is [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open, **which will clear the document**.

Comment: You might want to mention *why* document.write breaks the code. (It’s because it wipes out the JS code on the first iteration.)

Comment: I was looking for definitive documentation.  Yes. I do know what it does

Comment: @JaromandaX thx for the  quick reply, yes that solved the problem. However im still unclear as to why document.write does not work.

Comment: added some details